# Facebook Module dialog error picture is not formatted properly

Tags: android, facebook, image, formatting, titanium

How do you include a picture in Titanium's Facebook Module dialog? In Titanium's example, the picture property in the dialog is a link of a picture from a website:

```
var data = 
{
    link : "http://www.appcelerator.com",
    name : "Appcelerator Titanium Mobile",
    message : "Checkout this cool open source project for creating mobile apps",
    caption : "Appcelerator Titanium Mobile",
    picture : "http://developer.appcelerator.com/assets/img/DEV_titmobile_image.png",
    description : "You've got the ideas, now you've got the power. Titanium translates " +
              "your hard won web skills into native applications..."
};

fb.dialog("feed", data, function(e) 
{
    if(e.success && e.result) 
    {
        alert("Success! New Post ID: " + e.result);
    } 
    else 
    {
        if(e.error) 
        {
            alert(e.error);
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert("User canceled dialog.");
        }
    }
});
```

But what if you want to use a picture that's local and NOT via a link of a website like this?

```
var data = 
{
    link: "http://play.google.com/",
    name: "Android app's name",
    picture: "file:///data/data/com.appid/app_appdata/directory/name-of-image.jpg"
};
```

I get the picture property formatting error if I use the code above. See this image for visual reference: http://postimg.org/image/wjefdlalb/

I've tried using the FileSystem like this:

```
function getFile() 
{
    var imageFileToPost;
    var imageFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile("file:///data/data/com.appid/app_appdata/directory/name-of-image.jpg");

    if (imageFile.exists()) 
    {
        console.log("exists");
        imageFileToPost = imageFile.read();
    }

    return imageFileToPost;
}

var data = 
{
    link: "http://play.google.com/",
    name: "Android app's name",
    picture: getFile() 
};
```

And the post is successful, there are no errors BUT the picture was NOT published on Facebook.

**Note:** I would use the graph but I need to use permissions like 'publish_actions' which means I have to to have Facebook review the app but they don't like prefill messages even when the user can edit message anyways. So is this really just a formatting issue with Facebook Module's dialog or it only takes URLs of a picture? If it's a formatting issue, can anyone tell me how to format this correctly because I really need to use the picture that's local and not from a website?

Comment: you may want to check [this post](http://www.titaniumtutorial.com/2012/03/create-album-and-post-photos-in.html)

Comment: Hi Turtle, thanks for your time but I'd rather not use the Graph. I used the graph and used publish_actions but was rejected by Facebook because I had prefill messages that the user can edit. Facebook just doesn't like the prefill messagesa & the dialog lets me have that prefill data like links & a picture without having to ask Facebook's permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is maybe a bit late, but I had the same issue recently.

It does not seem to be possible with the current version of the Facebook module to create a dialog to share local images.

Because I also needed this functionality for one of my apps, I forked the module (https://github.com/dthulke/ti.facebook) and added a method `presentPhotoShareDialog` which takes an image blob as argument. Unfortunately it only works if the native Facebook app is installed.

Example:

```
if (fb.getCanPresentShareDialog()) {
    fb.presentPhotoShareDialog({
        imageBlob : view.toImage()
    });
}
```